# 5,6-dihydrouracil and 5,6-dihydroxyuracil - how they arise in DNA?

Tags: biochemistry, dna

5,6-dihydrouracil can be formed from cytosine after exposure of DNA to ionizing radiation under anoxic conditions [<sup>[**Ref**]</sup>](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8524238). What are other ways by which 5,6-dihydrouracil is formed in DNA? What about 5,6-dihydroxyuracil?

Comment: [Here is the pubmed link to the paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8524238). I couldn't think of an appropriate way to edit the question to incorporate the link.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Correction: 5,6-dihydroxyuracil does in fact exist. http://www.chemindustry.com/chemicals/0930310.html

Comment: @MarchHo Thanks. I nominated the post for reopen.

Answer (score 1):

[Dihydrouracil oxidase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihydrouracil_oxidase) can catalyse the reduction of uracil to dihydrouracil in the presence of hydrogen peroxide. The reduction of uracil to dihydrouracil can also be catalysed by [dihydrouracil dehydrogenase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihydrouracil_dehydrogenase_(NAD%2B)) using NADH.

According to [this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1146717/), 5,6-dihydroxycytosine can be formed by treating cytosine or DNA with osmium tetroxide, an extremely strong oxidising agent. Since they are both pyrimidines (and in fact cytosine often [spontaneously hydrolyses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deamination#Cytosine) to uracil), uracil will also be affected by the same oxidation. 5,6-dihydroxyuracil was also detected within the oxidised DNA sample as a result of oxidation and demethylation of thymine.

> The presence of 5,6-dihydroxyuracil (peak 11 in
>   Fig. 1) can be explained analogously to the formation
>   of 5-hydroxy-5-methylbarbituric acid from thymine on
>   permanganate oxidation (lida & Hayatsu, 1970, 1971)
>   (Scheme 2). The actual oxidation products ofcytosine, i.e.
>   structures (I) and (II), were not observed in DNA. As the
>   calf thymus DNA used in this work did not contain uracil,
>   the uracil derivatives discussed above could not have been
>   formed from uracil in DNA.